# How to creat a event Trigger when download is finished

Tags: java, android, eventtrigger

am writing a downloadManager and i need a hint. there i could create an event an fire it when ever i wanted. but i cant seem to find how to do that in java. what i want to do is i want to create an event for my class and then fire it inside one of the classes' member methods. now when ever this Class is called and sees that the download is finish(i.e. some variable has reached 100 for example) it fires an event indicating the situation. how can i create that in java?

```
public class DownloadManager
    {
        static Queue<AvailableGame> downloadQueue;
        static Integer currenProgress;
        static String currentDownload;
        static Boolean isRunning;


        /**
         * Start download
         */
        public void startDownloading()
        {

            AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask()
            {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects)
                {
                    downloadNextFile();
                    return null;

        private static String downloadFile(String downloadUrl)
        {
            String toDownload = downloadUrl;
            String fileName = getFileNameFromUrl(toDownload);

            // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
            // presses the power button during download
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)
            MainActivity.getContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "DownloadManager");
            wl.acquire();

            try
            {
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL(toDownload);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();

                    // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                    // instead of the file
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                    {
                        return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode() + " "
                        + connection.getResponseMessage();
                    }    

                    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    // download the file
                    input = connection.getInputStream();
                    output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fileName);

                    byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
                    {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        if (fileLength > 0)
                        {
                            currenProgress = ((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                            currentDownload = "Downloading " + fileName;
                        }
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return e.toString();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (output != null)
                        {
                            output.close();
                        }
                        if (input != null)
                        {
                            input.close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ignored)
                    {
                    }

                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                wl.release();
            }
            return null;
        }   


    }
```

> How can i save information when my download is finish,the second probleem is how to a

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should be using Android's [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) for this. If you are, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` that detects when a download is finished.

There is a full example you can download and run on your phone with full source code for you to see how this can be done: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite/T16-Update

Check specifically the files [DownloadCheckService.java](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/EmPubLite/T16-Update/src/com/commonsware/empublite/DownloadCheckService.java) and [DownloadCompleteReceiver.java](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/EmPubLite/T16-Update/src/com/commonsware/empublite/DownloadCompleteReceiver.java).

Hope it helps.